# Installing after downgrade

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel

Ubuntu kernel on a remote server (14.04) was downgraded from 119 (apparently there was a glitch that damaged nvidia drivers) to 4.4.0-116. Whenever I'm trying to install anything, I keep getting the error message

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic:
     linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
    Package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic is not configured yet
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure)
```

and similar.

Is there any way to fix it without purging anything? I'm not a big Linux (let alone server) expert, so just don't want to crash anything and make things even worse.

EDIT:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143~14.04.1) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (= 4.4.0.119.100); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-generic-lts-xenial


sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143~14.04.1) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-generic-No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                       lts-xenial (= 4.4.0.119.100); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-generic-lts-xenial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Different kernel versions are usually installed as separate packages. What commands have you used to "downgrade"? What happens if you remove the 4.4.0-119 kernel?

Comment: I didn't do it; one of our IT specialsts did, he said something wasn't right with the way 119 worked with nvidia drivers. I don't know what happens if I remove 119, and I'm too afraid to check

Comment: Was trying to find info about this issue online and I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8/+bug/1750937), BUT that says that the issue is with both 116 and 119, and 112 was the last working revision. So I don't know if that's the issue the IT specialist was referring to. It would be good to know more information.

Comment: I'll need some more information.  Put the results of `apt-get -f install` and `dpkg --configure -a` in your answer.  Feel free to use pastebin if it's a lot of output.  Also, if apt-get -f install is asking to remove things and you are not comfortable with them, you can say no, but still put up the output.

Comment: @dpb: I've added the outputs. It either some dependencies problem or configuration